# Can any posterior follow given an appropriate prior?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Let's assume we are given some observation $x$, and two distributions $p(x | \theta)$ and $p(\theta | x)$. What are the necessary conditions that allow a prior $p(\theta)$ to exist, such that Bayes' Theorem holds and $p(\theta|x)$ is the correct posterior following $p(\theta | x) = p(\theta) p(x | \theta) / p(x)$?

I have only ever seen Bayes' rule in terms of probability densities but I guess you could think of it in terms of general probability measures $\mathcal{M}(\theta)$ on $\theta$. So for an experiment with fixed observation $x_0$ and likelihood $p(x|\theta)$ we could think of it as an operation $\mathcal{B}_{x_0, p(x_0|\theta)}: \mathcal{M}(\theta) \rightarrow \mathcal{M}(\theta)$ that takes in a prior and updates our beliefs into a posterior. Are there any results what properties this operation has?

Philosophically, I guess this question translates into: Can two persons who agree about the state of the world (i.e. $x$) and the way the world works (i.e. $p(x|\theta)$) come to arbitrary different conclusions (i.e. any posterior $p(\theta|x)$) if they only start with different opinions (i.e. $p(\theta)$) or are there some conclusions that you should never reach regardless of your prior opinion.

Comment: Intuitively it is clear that if for some specific value $\theta_0$ of $\theta$ it is impossible for $x$ to occur, our posterior after actually observing $x$ with our own eyes should yield $p(\theta_0|x) = 0$, regardless of what $p$ does on the other values of $\theta$. So strictly speaking the answer to your question is no. But probabilities of 0 and 1 could be considered 'unphysical' and if we made a promise that we wouldn't consider them anyway (in our priors and our understanding of how the world works) then I am not so sure what the answer to your problem is

Comment: Yes, I was aware that densities with a different support would not work but I admit that the title of the question was a bit too simplified. That's why i was more specific in the text and asked for conditions that would allow a positive answer. But thanks for giving it a thought anyways!